# ¿Cómo importar muchas imágenes desde una carpeta del proyecto a código en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, imagen, javascript-import

Yo importo regularmente una imagen de la siguiente manera:

```
import img from './assets/img.jpg';
```

Pero quiero obtener todas las imágenes que estén dentro de assets, ¿cómo hago sin hardcodear?

O sea, esto me parece pésimo en caso de que tenga muchas imágenes:

```
import img1 from './assets/img1.jpg';
import img2 from './assets/img2.jpg';
import img3 from './assets/img3.jpg';
// ...
import imgN from './assets/imgN.jpg';
```

Comment: probaste un glob? onda `import preloadImages from './assets/img*.jpg'; console.log(preloadImages);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que podrias intentar es en tu folder donde tienes tus imagenes /assets crear un archivo index.js donde "exportes" las imagenes

/assets
  index.js
  img1.jpg
  img2.jpg
  imgN.jpg

en tu archivo index

```
export { default as img1 } from './img1.jpg';
export { default as img2 } from './img2.jpg';
export { default as imN } from './imgN.gif';
```

y en tu archivo donde quieres importar las imagenes

```
import * as AllImages from './assets/index.js'
console.log(allImages);
```

Espero te ayude.